# From when does the operating systems sign the updates?

Tags: updates

Which was the year the linux distributions, windows have first used to sign their updates? Historical question that is hard to "google".

Comment: This will vary on a distro-to-distro basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [apt package manager](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt)

> In recent releases, Debian has been using strong crypto to 
>   validate downloaded packages. This is commonly called
>   "secure apt" (or "apt-secure") and was implemented in Apt
>   **version 0.6 in 2003, which Debian migrated to in 2005**.

Although work for the underlying [dpkg-verify had started since 2000](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/dpkg/debsig-verify.git/tree/debian/changelog?id=b88d15d1cbdc59c525869c299e2131fd965073d0).

From [rpm change log](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/master/CHANGES), rpm seems to support PGP, presumably for code signing, since at least version 2.0, which was released [around 1996](http://rpm.org/timeline.html).

Windows is a bit difficult to research. There are evidence [that Windows 98 had support for signed hotfixes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/206071):

> Installing Windows 98 and Windows 98 Second Edition Hotfixes
>
> ... To install a Windows 98 and Windows 98 Second Edition
>   hotfix on a single computer, run the self-extracting installer.
>   This installer performs the following actions:
>
> 1. Unpacks the files that are needed for installation into a
>      temporary folder. Typically, these files include:
>
>    - ...
>    - A digital signature file (.cat) used to digitally sign 
>        the hotfix binary files (in most situations).
>    - ...

However, I'm not quite sure what Microsoft means by "in most situation", perhaps it doesn't always require hotfix packages to be signed?

Comment: @pepite: I added some bit about Windows.